# PHP Multiple 2/3-D Arrays sorting, adding, removing

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

Ok so Basically I have 4 arrays. 2 Built based on an original query that uses cURL to get a list of names and email address's from a partner site of sorts, the other array is just the email address's from that same site for use in a query to my database, so I can see whether or not the email address's obtained are in my DB or not, which if they are then the ones that are go into another array while the ones that aren't go into yet another array. I mean I could be thinking this through way to much. But what I have a need for is those name and those email address's. That first array looks like..

```
Array(
  [errors] = "none",
  [output] = Array (
             array(name, email)
             array(name, email)
             array(name, email)
             array(name, email)
             array(name, email)
  )
)
```

Then the second array I have is basically

```
Array(email, email, email, email)
```

From which I implode() it for use in a IN() query to my DB to see whats in, whats not. My problem here is I am loosing my names now and essentially the first array becomes pointless. However I guess what I am trying to figure out is there a way where I can keep the first array and break it apart for use in the 3rd and 4th arrays I mentioned above.

I guess another good question is. Am I even approaching the logic correctly? is there another way I can tackle this without so many arrays?

Comment: Why not just have a Class, with properties name, email, and is_in_database; and then have an array of objects?

Comment: not sure if I follow what your attempting to imply.

Comment: Just that one array of objects seems simpler than four arrays with redundant data in them. In response to your last paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a single array using email as key and do all operations on that.

```
Array(
  'test@test.com' => Array(
    'name' => 'Mr Test',
    'duplicate' => 0
  ),
  'foo@bar.com' => Array(
    'name' => 'Bond, James',
    'duplicate' => 0
  )
)
```

Create a temporary string for your database query, either from this new array or while you're building it from the original data.

When checking results for duplicates simply set duplicate in the array. Then you can later loop through and do operations based on that.

Hope that helps?